# join mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this query which is working fine:

```
$query = "SELECT adafruit_articles.id, adafruit_articles.title, adafruit_articles.timestamp  FROM adafruit_articles WHERE MONTH(timestamp)='$m' LIMIT 5";
```

I also have another database called adafruit_images that has the name of the image(s) for each article (some articles have no image, some have more).

The structure looks like this:

```
id  articleid   image
```

I want to combine the query from above that it also grabs the images.
I'm only not that good in mysql so i was hoping someone could help.

Comment: Do you have another table not database, is it ?

Comment: you have examples in mysql documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT adafruit_articles.id, adafruit_articles.title, adafruit_articles.timestamp
FROM adafruit_articles
LEFT OUTER JOIN adafruit_images ON adafruit_images.articleid = adafruit_articles.id
WHERE MONTH(timestamp)='$m'
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: It should work, you are probably doing something wrong, but query is correct. Are you trying this in your php application or mysql console?

Comment: Then you have mistake while outputting related rows, can't tell more without your code.

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT adafruit_articles.id, adafruit_articles.title, adafruit_articles.timestamp
FROM adafruit_articles 
JOIN adafruit_images
ON adafruit_images.articleid = adafruit_articles.id
WHERE MONTH(timestamp)='$m' 
LIMIT 5
```